# Асинхронность в C#

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Мне нужно реализовать асинхронную работу UI и алгоритма в своей программе. Я уже делал что-то подобное в прошлом, но тогда мой алгоритм ничего не возвращал, а только работал с файлами. Примерно это выглядело так:

```
async void CopyFiles(DirectoryInfo dir) {
  var len = await Task.Run(() => dir.GetFiles().Length);

  var p = new Progress<int>(i => {
    progress.Text = i + " файлов из " + len + " отсортировано";
    pBar.PerformStep();
  });

  await Task.Run(() => RealCopyFiles(dir, p));
  bDone.Visible = true;
}

void RealCopyFiles(DirectoryInfo dir, IProgress<int> progress) {
  var i = 0;
  foreach (var k in dir.GetFiles()) {
    string month = k.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM");

    //...

    i += 1;
    progress.Report(i);
  }
}
```

В `CopyFiles` я вызывал `RealCopyFiles`, который оповещал о прогрессе.
 Теперь мне нужно, что бы `RealCopyFiles` ещё и возвращал значение. Следовательно, в месте, где я вызываю `CopyFiles` мне нужно присвоить результат работы метода `RealCopyFiles` другой переменной. Но как бы я не пытался, компилятор всегда ругается, что нельзя такое делать с асинхронными методами(я как бы и не против, просто по другому я не знаю как это сделать).
То каким образом можно реорганизовать данный код с учётом того, что `RealCopyFiles`, а следовательно и `CopyFiles` должны возвращать значение?

Добавил поточный пример:

```
public int[,] getCrossCorrelation(byte[,] main_Image, byte[,] template_image)
        {
            //..

                rowsCompleted++;

                progressBar1.Value = (int)(((double)rowsCompleted / height) * 100);
         //..

            return crossCorelation;
        }
```

С этого метода я хотел бы вынести обработку прогресс бара в отдельный поток.
Но если делать это по аналогии с предыдущим примером, я не могу вернуть результат работы этого метода в асинхронный метод, который, в свою очередь, должен так же вернуть этот результат в том месте, где он вызывается

Что имею на данный момент:

```
public int[,] getCrossCorrelation(byte[,] main_Image, byte[,] template_image, IProgress<int> progress)
        {
/..
                rowsCompleted++;

                currentProgress = (int)(((double)rowsCompleted / height) * 100);
                progress.Report(currentProgress);

/..
            return crossCorelation;
        }

async Task<int[,]> test()
        {
            var p = new Progress<int>(currentProgress =>
            {
                progressBar1.Value = currentProgress;
            });
            var value = await Task.Run(() => getCrossCorrelation(byteImageMain, byteImageTemplate, p));

            return value;

        }


 private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        /..
            int[,] crossCorelation = test(); //<-- тут ошибка
    }
```

Ошибка:неявное преобразование типа "System.Threading.Tasks.Task" в "int[*,*]" невозможно.

Comment: как минимум нужно чтобы эти функции возвращали значение

Comment: какое значение вы хотите вернуть?

Comment: @AntonPapin обновил пост

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> компилятор всегда ругается, что нельзя такое делать с асинхронными
>   методами

Очень даже можно. Ну или покажите, *как именно* вы это делаете и *что именно* говорит компилятор. Вот так все работает:

```
int RealCopyFiles(DirectoryInfo dir, IProgress<int> progress)
{
    //...
    return 42;
}

async Task<int> CopyFiles(DirectoryInfo dir) {
    //...
    var value = await Task.Run(() => RealCopyFiles(dir, p)); // value = 42
    //...
    return value;
}
```

**UPD**

Поскольку метод теперь возвращает таск, этот метод *тоже надо await'ить*:

```
private async void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //..
    int[,] crossCorelation = await test(); //<-- тут ошибка
}
```

Поскольку все это дело происходит в обработчике события, а он не может возвращать `Task`, тело метода крайне желательно обернуть в `try/catch`. Почему -- [смотрите тут](https://youtu.be/lh8cT6qI-nA?t=1670).

Comment: странно, я пробовал практически таким же образом, но не получалось. сейчас попробую

Comment: у меня получается ошибка в том месте, где я вызываю `copyFiles`  и пытаюсь передать результат исполнения `copyFiles`, который на самом деле является результатом исполнения `realCopyFiles`, переменной в третей функции. ошибка: `неявное преобразование типа "System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int[*,*]>" в "int[*,*]" невозможно.`

Comment: @newbie код-то покажете, или мне надо достать свой хрустальный шар? :)

Comment: @andreycha, его не надо доставать, его не надо было убирать :-)

Comment: @andreycha Сейчас опять обновлю вопрос

Comment: @newbie обновил ответ.

Comment: @andreycha "Оператор await можно использовать только в методах с модификатором async. Попробуйте пометить этот метод модификатором async и изменить типа его возвращаемого значения на Task". Но ведь тогда не получится решить мою задачу.

Comment: @newbie обратите внимание, что я пометил метод `btnStart_Click` модификатором `async`. *"Но ведь тогда не получится решить мою задачу"* -- ваша задача вроде как заключается в возвращении значения из асинхронного метода. Причем здесь наличие или отсутствие модификатора `async`?

Comment: @andreycha +Респект. Всё работает. Хотя я был уверен, что у меня не правильный в корни подход. А по поводу моего последнего комментария: я имел в виду именно тип Task.

Answer (score 2):

Асинхронный метод должен возвращать `Task`, `Task<Т>` либо ничего не возвращать (`void`). Почитать можно здесь https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/mt674882.aspx

```
async Task<int> MyMethodAsync()
{ 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну а если мне нужно всё таки вернуть значение?

Answer (score 1):

Может вам поможет документация на [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/mt674893.aspx)?

```
// Описание асинхроного метода
async Task<MyClass> GetMyClassAsync()  
{
    MyClass myClassObject = new MyClass();

    // Do Somethisng
    return myClassObject;  
}  

// Получение результата
MyClass result = await GetMyClassAsync();
```